# Elastic search browser/url bar GET request

Tags: regex, url, browser, get, elasticsearch

I am trying to execute an elastic search query, eventually with an angular.get call, but for the time being I cannot get it to work even in the browser URL bar. Here is my URL.

```
server_loc/index-1,index-2/_search?pretty=true&source=%22{query:{regexp:{col_name:BBG}}}%22&size=10&from=0
```

I know that at least setting the "q" variable within the URL causes me to get the correct results. For example..

```
server_loc/index-1,index-2/_search?pretty=true&q=col_name:BBG&size=10&from=0
```

This much works. However, I would like to make a query based on reg expressions. The results that DO get returned from the first URL are simply the first 10 things in my index, and a control-F for "BBG" turns up empty. So it is getting something but not what I want.

Help?

Comment: I figured this out. Here is the query that worked for me. 
server_loc/index-1,index-2/_search?pretty=true&source={%22query%22:{%22match%22:{%22col_name%22:%22bbg%22}}}&size=10&from=0

Comment: notably, the letters had to be in lower case. weird